# Azure Service Bus, where are outgoing messages on my local computer?

Tags: c#, azure, messaging, amqp, servicebus

When I send a message to the Azure Service Bus, do they first go to an outgoing queue on my computer?

When I worked with MSMQ in a different project (not Azure) I could visualize this process with QueueExplorer. Is there a way to do this with the Azure Service Bus?

Comment: There's Service Bus explorer which is a desktop app that you can use to peek at messages or read and delete (just google for it)

Comment: I am fairly confident that the connection has to be live. if not it is not stored locally. You should just get an error about the SB host not found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All sends to Service Bus are remote. There is no local queue.